# Fill and array and then remove its items

Tags: swift

I receive the data from websocket in every second and I want to take 8 of them in an array and send to the different endpoint, and when the first 8 items is added, I want to remove all items inside the array and fill with the new ones, here is my codes:

```
if dataArray.count <= 7 {
        dataArray.append(value)
        
        if dataArray.count == 8 {
           self.sendData(data: dataArray)
           dataArray.removeAll()
   }
 }
```

Just want to know that there is a better / safer way to do that?

Thank you so much

Comment: Your first if is incorrect, it should have a } after append and then an else `if dataArray.count <= 7 { dataArray.append(value) } else { self.sendData(data: dataArray) dataArray.removeAll() }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine, if you are worry about condition race, maybe consider below

- Make a copy array before sending:
  `let valuesToSend = dataArray`
- Replace old one with new array once reach 8 items:
  `dataArray = [Data]()`

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if you need the first comparison.

```
dataArray.append(value)

if dataArray.count == 7 {
    sendData(data: dataArray)
    dataArray.removeAll()
}
```

And since you want the first 8 elements, shouldn't you compare the count with 8?

Also, you might want to check what happens in a possible overflow case (count > 8).

Another approach would be using a switch case

```
dataArray.append(value)
switch dataArray.count {
case 8:
    sendData(data: dataArray)
    dataArray.removeAll()
case 9...:
    fatalError("Should never happen")
default:
}
```